# Select all rows that have same ID

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
ID | Part
1  | A
1  | B
1  | C
2  | B
2  | C
3  | A
3  | D
3  | E
4  | B
4  | D
```

and want a query that will grab all ID's that have an A, and return a list of all other parts with that ID.

e.g: Want Parts related to B:

```
Part | Count
 A   | 1
 C   | 2
 D   | 1
```

What I have currently:

```
SELECT * FROM tble WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tble t WHERE Part = ?)
GROUP BY Part ORDER BY COUNT(Part) DESC
```

This works, but is quite slow and I'm looking to improve it, but having difficulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not unreasonable, although the `distinct` is unnecessary and I would use `exists` rather than `in`.  And, the outer `select` needs to be fixed for the aggregation

```
SELECT t.part, COUNT(*)
FROM tble t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tble t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND t2.Part = ?)
GROUP BY t.Part
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Then, to optimize this query, you want an index:

```
create index idx_tble_id_part on tble(id, part);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify this..  Once you have the logic down, then add back in the SELECT * FROM..

```
SELECT Part, COUNT(Part) As Count_of_Part
GROUP BY Part ORDER BY COUNT(Part) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a join from the table back to itself on ID, and then count the distinct values that pop up:

```
SELECT b.part, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)
FROM 
    table as a 
    INNER JOIN table as b ON
        a.id = b.id AND
        a.part <> b.part
WHERE
    a.part = 'B'
GROUP BY b.part
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done by joining back to the table:

```
SELECT t1.part
,count(*)
FROM tble t1
INNER JOIN tble t ON t.id = t1.id
                  AND t.part = 'B'
                  AND t1.part <> t.part
GROUP BY t1.part
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30043/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by grouping the data.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT part, COUNT(id) AS TotalCountId
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ID
```